# PHP+HTML: List -> Details flow

Tags: php, html

I have a list of items in a table and next to the items I have a "show details" element. This element has:

```
onClick="drilldown(this.id)";

function drilldown(aClickedId) {
    // do magic, redirect to showDetails.html?id=aClickedId
}
```

Then I want to pass the ID as a parameter to a HTML page and redirect the user to it. The HTML page will call a php script that populates the view with data from the DB in the appropriate section:

**showDetails.html**:

```
<?php 
    $_GET['id'] = getIdFromURL();
    include "showDetails.php"; ?>
```

Is this the right approach? if so, how to send a parameter to "showDetails.php" when I'm "including" it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can redirect in Javascript:

```
function drilldown(aClickedId) {
    window.location = "showDetails.html?id=" + aClickedId;
}
```

By default your `showDetails.html` will not execute the PHP code within it because only `.php` files will be parsed and executed as PHP. It is possible to configure your web server to parse and execute `.html` files but it won't by default.

You don't need this:

```
$_GET['id'] = getIdFromURL();
```

All you need to do is, within showDetails.php, use `$_GET['id']`. All includes will have access to the `$_GET` array because it is a superglobal. When a script is included, it is simply inserted into that point and is executed as if it is part of the parent and so it will have access to all variables and functions that are available at the point of inclusion.

It's hard to comment on whether this approach is best practice because I don't think there is enough info about what you're doing. For example, if the element that takes the click is an anchor (`<a></a>`) then you don't need the Javascript redirect at all, just put the ID into the href.

Comment: Thank you, but this was not the issue (how to redirect via my approach). I am asking if my approach is correct (best practice) and also how to send a parameter to a PHP script I'm calling via "include showDetails.php". My web server is already configured to parse and execute php calls from html.

Comment: See my edit. Are you trying to insert the result of showDetails into the current page, without doing a full page reload/redirect? If so, you need to use ajax to get the content and do the partial page update, instead of a redirect.

Comment: No, not in the current page. From page1 -> redirect page2: insert showDetails.php. Thanks for the detailed answer, I'll give it a go!

Answer (score 1):

I didn't understand what is the exact problem. In my view you can pass the id parameter via a get method since you are redirecting the user to showDetails.php

```
$id = ""; // store the value of id

<a href="showDetails.php?id=$id">Show Details</a>
```

Comment: Because I don't want the .php file to generate all the html code (this is already in the HTML file), just a tiny section with a few fields. Does this make sense?

Comment: Won't this redirect the browser to a new page? in that page (PHP script), will I have to construct all the HTML code?